# How many images per .tfrecord file (for training tensorflow object detection API)?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, google-cloud-ml, object-detection-api, tfrecord

In the object detection API [using your own data set](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md) docs, it is described how to shard the entire training set into multiple files. However, they only say

> "When you have more than a few thousand examples, it is beneficial to shard your dataset into multiple files: ..."

I would like to know a good number of splits as a function of the number of images to be trained on.

Is there an optimal size in terms of the **number of instances** per file, or is the **file size** more important?

(In case that changes anything, I ultimately want to train object detection API models on Google AI platform.) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) have more files than the number of workers/gpus so that each worker can read its own file.

(2) try to have files each of which is several hundred MB because GCS has high throughout but high time to first byte.

Comment: So there is no reason to have more than {num_workers} files? E.g., if I use one TPU, one huge .tfrecord file is fine?

Comment: if you use only one TPU *core*, then, yes, one large file is fine.

Comment: Thanks, @Lak! Do you have any links to any documentation that back up all your claims (which seem all reasonable anyway)?

Comment: The TF team rule-of-thumb for sharding image TF records is 100 to 200 images per tfrecord file.